# Creating an instance of an enum from it's type

Tags: swift, enums

I am looking for a way to get an enum value from an integer using it's type.

Here's an example of what I want to do;

```
enum TestEnum: Int {
    case A = 0
    case B = 1
    case C = 2
}

func createEnum<T>(value: Int, type: T.Type) -> T? {
    // Some magic here
}

let a = createEnum(0, type: TestEnum.self) // Optional(TestEnum.A)
let b = createEnum(1, type: TestEnum.self) // Optional(TestEnum.B)
let c = createEnum(2, type: TestEnum.self) // Optional(TestEnum.C)
let invalid = createEnum(3, type: TestEnum.self) // nil
```

I know you can get the value like so:

```
let a = TestEnum(rawValue: 0) // Optional(TestEnum.A)
let b = TestEnum(rawValue: 1) // Optional(TestEnum.B)
let c = TestEnum(rawValue: 2) // Optional(TestEnum.C)
let invalid = TestEnum(rawValue: 4) // nil
```

However I'd like to be able to "store" the type of enum to create (in this case, `TestEnum`) and then create it later from a value, as seen in my example.

Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumeration with an underlying type conform to the `RawRepresentable`
protocol which has `RawValue` as associate type:

```
func createEnum<T : RawRepresentable >(value: T.RawValue, type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return T(rawValue: value)
}
```

That would work for your `enum TestEnum: Int { ... }` example, but is not
restricted to `Int` as underlying type.

```
enum StrEnum : String {
    case X = "x"
    case Y = "y"
}

let x = createEnum("x", type: StrEnum.self) // Optional(StrEnum.X)
```

*If* you want to restrict the function to enums with underlying type `Int` then add another constraint on the generic placeholder:

```
func createEnum<T : RawRepresentable where T.RawValue == Int>(value: Int, type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return T(rawValue: value)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to constrain the RawRepresentable to one where RawValue is an Int?